# How can I display the product short description in the related product template?

Tags: magento-1, related-products

I need to display the related product short description in a magento 1.9 store.  What do I need to add to the template->catalog->product->list->related.phtml file?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that before, but I think you can check if in `Mage::registry` you can access displayed product object. If so, than you should be able to do render info, using some method like `$this->getRelatedProduct()->getShortDescription`. 
Registry would be the first for me to look for.

Comment: not sure how to check the registry?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506492/magento-get-current-product

and look at this: 
http://prattski.com/2014/09/23/using-the-magento-registry-mageregister/